# Not getting author email in comments/replies from gsuite comments list api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Trying to fetch all comments and replies using [comment listing api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list) & [replies listing api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/replies/list) for gsuite drive files by using domain wide delegation as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation).

I am getting comments & replies perfectly and as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments) am getting author object as well in api response for both comments/replies.

But only `emailAddress` key is missing from author. Haven't found any documentation as well which explains reason for this.

But for analysis purpose author email id is super important for us. Is there anything which I am missig or some bug from google side ?

Comment: So you're receiving all the other fields inside of the `author` with the exception of `emailAddress`?

Comment: Yes @ScottMcC I am getting all other details of author

Comment: Hmmm... that's highly unusual, emailAddress should be returned when you're querying all the comments

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a bug, you may check the [How to Get Help](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/support) page of Google Drive API. You can [search the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191650%2B%20type:bug) to determine if it is a known issue. If the issue is completely new, you can [report it on the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909) as well.